# Which Ubuntu images for AWS: Hammond's or Canonical's?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services

I've used AWS and various forms of Linux over the past few years, but am wondering if anyone has any experience using Canonical's AWS Ubuntu images and can compare them to Hammond's.  Hammond's images are very well put together, with a deep understanding of AWS optimizations and such, but Canonical has more intimate knowledge of their distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally use Hammond's over Canonical's, but not for any particularly deep reason. The Canonical images don't allow you to log in as root while Hammond's do, and while I understand the former is better from a security perspective, the applications I needed to run need to be able to ssh in as root. This made Hammond's amis optimal for programming with, at least for me.